# Angular overload template

Tags: angular

I have a very common/basic need that I can't get my head around:

I have a basic template which is composed of three layout components:

- Sidenav
- Header
- Body

Each of my model components let's say User and Car will have to extend the Header and Body components by setting different data but keeping the main css in Body and Header the same.

I have tried to implement the following in the model components:

**user.component.html**

```
<div class="bc-content">
  <app-header [title]="title" [breadcrumbs]="breadcrumbs"></app-header>
  <app-body [data]="data"><!-- I wish to have specific implementation in here --></app-body>
</div>
```

How can I overload the template with specific implementation per component (User, Car, etc).

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened disableClose>
    <app-bc-sidenav></app-bc-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can provide only one HTML file for a comment. If you want to use some html, which you want to insert dynamically then use ng-template. You can use it as html container. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/
But i will recommend you to use routing here to meet your expectations. In routing inside your body component, according to route you can show user and car by using two seperate components.
If anything common there then create a layout template for reusing code.https://codeburst.io/angular-4-6-routing-be185fcf85aa

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `Car` and a `User` components I assume you have a routing set.

Thus you simply need to create a wrapper (shell)

wrapper.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-nav></app-nav>

<router-outler></router-outler>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

And then declare in your routes

```
const routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: WrapperComponent,
   children: [
     { path: 'car', component: CarComponent },
     // and any components you need to have these common parts
   ]
  }
// here goes the rest of routes
...
];
```

Comment: Added the code from root component to show that the router is already there. So since the header layout is exactly the same for all components I do not want to repeat the same code everywhere. This is provided out of the box in other frameworks

Comment: You can nest as many `path: '', children: []` for wrappers as you need

Comment: Can you provide an example for my usecase, not really sure how this will work